# Why doesn't core pass unit tests out of the box?

Tags: 8, testing

I’m on Travis CI, trying to diagnose some issues. In the process I found many unit tests failing. I originally though my module was causing issues, but it turn out that core fails many unit tests all on its own given my basic setup. What am I missing to get Drupal to pass:

```
cd ..
git clone https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git
cd drupal
git checkout 8.8.x
export COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1
composer update phpunit/phpunit symfony/phpunit-bridge phpspec/prophecy symfony/yaml doctrine/common doctrine/annotations --with-dependencies
vendor/bin/phpunit -c core/phpunit.xml.dist --testsuite=unit
```

The result is

```
Tests: 18995, Assertions: 33695, Errors: 33, Failures: 57, Skipped: 2543, Incomplete: 3.
```

When (if) I get this working, I would like to add in the Kernel tests. I’ve already been able to successfully run the database and entity layer kernel tests with MySQL.

All of the errors are related to Doctrine:

```
 Failed asserting that exception of type "Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationException" matches expected exception "\InvalidArgumentException". Message was: "[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Annotation\Enum" in property Drupal\Tests\Component\Annotation\Doctrine\Fixtures\AnnotationEnumLiteralInvalid::$value does not exist, or could not be auto-loaded." at /home/travis/build/Beakerboy/drupal/vendor/doctrine/annotations/lib/Doctrine/Common/Annotations/AnnotationException.php:54
```

Comment: Don't agree w/ the close vote on this. It is a pretty clear question.

Comment: This is an off-site issue related to core/contrib development related to the sql server module and running tests. There's been discussion on Slack as well.

Comment: That’s me asking in slack. This question here is not necessarily related to the sqlsrv module, since ANY user may want to test core for one reason or another.